# Shopware 6 import/export Layout

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I need to create several layouts on my local instance and have to copy them on the staging and prod instances.

I am wondering if there is any possibility to export/import layouts?

Comment: I believe this is on the roadmap for one of the paid Shopware versions

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable with DB-migrations, all the required information is stored in the cms_* tables. See [CMS page table relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbOcF.png)

For only exporting certain layouts, this can be done with mysqldump --where option, there's a great example how this can be done [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4659)

Obviously if there's complicated layouts, you might need to require export/importing the required media/other data first.
It works when I tested it with a simple layout containing text/images/products, and by dumping/importing all the rows from the cms_* tables